# Time zone offset showing incorrect date and time

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I am trying to show time based on user local time zone. Server saves time to utc.

So, I have a date-time saved in my database.

`2018-10-03 05:55:51 // my server is digital ocean`

So now I am trying to console user local time. My time zone is set to 
`Sylhet Bangladesh`
Time offset is `-360`

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(offset) // offset is -360
var testDateUtc = moment.utc("2018-10-03 05:55:51");
var localDate = moment(testDateUtc).utcOffset(offset);
console.log(localDate.format("YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss"));
```

The above code prints incorrect date but correct time. 
`2018-02-10 11:55:51` the date is wrong.

I then changed my mac's time zone to `Dubai` which is `2 hours different then my country`

For dubai the offset is `-240` and it shows time 
`2018-03-10 01:55:51` this mean the date is correct but time is not correct.

Please help. Thank you.

**EDIT**
It works for most of the countries I tested like this 
`offset = Math.abs(offset)` so it always make it positive

Comment: If I understood, actually the date is right. If you subtract 6 hours from 05:55, you get 11:55(PM) for the day before. Sorry if I missed the point.

Comment: Maybe you meant `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` instead of `YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss` if you are concerned about the date?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to think about the offset.  Moment can do that for you:

```
moment.utc("2018-10-03 05:55:51").local().format()
```

Also, keep in mind that when you asked for the offset in your code, you asked for the *current* offset, which may or may not be the offset in effect at the time you're converting.  See "Offset != Time Zone" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).